# Troubles getting the difference between two dates with dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: php, date, datetime

I know this question has been asked a couple million times, and I believe I read them all but I somehow feel that I mixed up things, and I can have struggles to understand why.

My goal is to find if a date is older than 3mns, the "problem" is that the format is the following: `dd/mm/yyyy - HH:MM`.

Since the '-' is not accepted for a `DateTime` object, I removed it and made things easier by changing '/' to '-' in the date format itself:

```
$date = "12/02/2018 - 14:23";
// I have to go one by one or the format will be messed up
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $test);
$date = str_replace(' -', '', $date); //$date = 12-02-2018 14:23
$difference = time() - date($test);
```

When I write these lines, it's 12/02/2018 - 16:12, however, `$difference` returns `07:12:51`, while it should be around `01:49` (more or less)

I think `time()` is set up to be formatted to be `mm-dd-yyyy`, but how can I be sure, and how can I make everything work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`DateTime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and [`createFromFormat()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method to get this without any replacements:

```
$test = "12/02/2018 - 14:23";
$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y - H:i", $test);
$interval = $d1->diff(new DateTime());
// or $interval = $d1->diff(new DateTime("now", $timezone));
echo $interval->format("%H:%I:%S") ; // 01:58:43
```

Comment: I'm getting `06:58:22` with your answer but it looks sooo promising!

Comment: @Jaeger Really? Maybe the timezone. You could append the timezone in 3rd parameter of `createFromFormat()` and as 2nd parameter of  `new DateTime("now")`.

Comment: Damnit, I'm geting the same value even if I pass a timezone to both $d1 and "now"

Comment: @Jaeger What's happen if you just pass the timezone to `new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone("your time zone"))`, not in your `createFromFormat()`?

Comment: It worked, I forgot about my server's clock, so that's why the timezone wasn't good, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use your original string with strtotime() -

```
$test = "12/02/2018 - 14:23";
$newTime = strtotime(trim(str_replace('/', '-', str_replace('-', '', $test))));
//returns 1518441780
```

You can then use that to do your comparison:

```
$difference = time() - $newTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the replacing but with timezones. You say it's 16:12 for you, but your server probably has another timezone set, which is why you're getting the difference. Assuming you're in Madrid (which matches the time you're saying),

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$date = "12/02/2018 - 14:23";
// I have to go one by one or the format will be messed up
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
$date = str_replace(' -', '', $date); //$date = 12-02-2018 14:23
$difference = (time() - strtotime($date)) / 60 / 60;
echo $difference; // 2 hours and minutes
```

gives you the correct difference. I used [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to manually set a timezone. (You can use [`date_default_timezone_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) to see what timezone your server has by default)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kJYbD)

Notice I used `strtotime()` instead of date(), and divided by 3600 to get hours instead of seconds. You should probably use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead of tinkering with the date manually though.

Comment: With your solution I get `2.3569444444444`, but I have to thank you, because I forgot about my server's clock, so it led me to the problem, so thank you a lot!

Comment: It's no problem. What should the difference be? From 14:23 to 16:48 there's 2 hours and 25 minutes, which is close to what I get at least (`2.43444444444`). What are you expecting?

Comment: I guess you're right, I wasn't expected so much "4", I'm not used to timestamps in general

Comment: Oh, well that's just inherent of dividing by 60, you'll get repeating decimals most of the time :). Glad you could get it working. Good luck!